# how to specify build key in bitbucket's required build feature

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket

On Atlassian Bitbucket v8.5.1 there is a new feature, called "Required builds", where you can specify which build(s) should pass before merging a PR into a branch.

Info [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver085/checks-for-merging-pull-requests-1185452392.html?utm_campaign=in-app-help&utm_medium=in-app-help&utm_source=stash).

I find a bit difficult to understand which is the correct way of specifying the build key. The doc says:

> The build key of a Jenkins job is the name of each item in the path to
> the build, separated by a forward slash. For example; a folder called
> PROJ that contains a multibranch pipeline job called COREBUILDS, then
> the build key would be PROJ/COREBUILDS.

But my setup is simpler and doesn't involves multibranch pipeline jobs.
Does anybody have an idea on how to specify what they refer by "build key" in Jenkins?

Comment: https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BCLOUD-8305 apparently it's called `jobname` in jenkins

Comment: yeah I saw this post but even by using the pipeline job name, it is not recognized by bitbucket

Comment: I've tried every combination of the Jenkins path with no luck. I found [this Atlassian Community thread](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/Why-is-the-required-builds-merge-check-still-failing-after-a/qaq-p/2230801) that seems related. Unfortunately I am unable to test/modify the API Jenkins uses.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the [Stash/Bitbucket Notifier Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/stashNotifier/), it appears that the build key follows the format `<job_name>-<escaped_jenkins_url>`, where the Jenkins URL is obtained from the *Configure System* view of the server and slashes are escaped.

For example, if my job name was *Job-A* and my Jenkins server is configured with the URL *https://www.jenkins.com/* - the job key would be `Job-A-https:\\/\\/www.jenkins.com\\/`.

From Bitbucket, you can find existing build keys by using the UI API that populates the *Builds* tab of a PR.  Currently, that UI API URL is `<bitbucket url>/rest/ui/latest/projects/<project_slug>/repos/<repo_name>/pull-requests/<pr_id>/builds`.

Comment: Hitting the REST API as you linked was the _key_ for me ;)
Using the `key` property worked. Once typed into the pill box when configuring the required builds, it even showed the last build number as a tooltip.